In Zoom, how to have a different name on different devices?
I need to be able to join Zoom meetings from two different devices, for two different projects I'm involved with.  On my desktop, I have no webcam and we do audio only anyway.  I use my laptop (2018 Macbook Pro) for the project where we use webcams.
I would like to have my name appear differently on each device.  On my Desktop I want to append the project name after my name (JVC - Project Name) but on my laptop, I just want my name.  From what I can see there may only be one default name for the entire user's account.  I can change the name every time in the meeting, but that's annoying and I have to remember to do it.
Is what I'm seeking possible?

I think you are out of luck for the time being.
